# Finding single null vector of a large matrix

Tags: numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I am working with a large (for example, 40000 X 40001) sparse matrix which has only one null vector. Is there any efficient way to get the null vector without performing eigendecomposition? If yes, what is the time complexity?

I tried scipy.linalg.null_space but it's very slow. I found it slower than np.linalg.eigh

Comment: By null vector you mean a row in the matrix with all 0s? (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NullVector.html)

Comment: No, I mean if I multiply the large matrix with the vector then it would result a zero vector. $A v = 0$

Comment: Rank-revealing QR can do this too (`scipy.linalg.qr` with settings to make it rank-revealing), then take the last column. IDK how efficient it is and it still calculates the entire null space instead of just one vector.

Comment: QR decomposition is an O(n^3) process. I am looking for something which is O(n^2) or less. I forgot to mention that the matrix I am using is a sparse matrix. Sorry for that.